# How can I use COPY to import txt file into table WITHOUT the last row (footer)?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL, psql: I'm trying to import data into a table I just created using COPY, but the problem is that the TXT file contains a "footer" that gets rejected.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: <<FOOTER TEXT...>>
```

What is the best way to ignore the last row in the TXT file? (I don't want to have edit each of the TXT files I have to import). The "ideal" solution would be an option called FOOTER just like there is HEADER, but we don't have right? :-\

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe fix the file before you import it?  GNU versions ( at least) of the  UNIX `head` command can be given a negative number to exclude that many lines of the file.  With this approach, you'd make the file palatable to postgres before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

I could do the process in two steps:

First, use COPY to get all your data into a table that contains just one serial id and a text field. Once the data is there, delete de last row. I assume your text is tab delimited, and that you NEVER have a \x19 character in it.

You would create your temp table like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
(
    serial_id serial,
    all_text text
) ;

COPY temp_table  (all_text)
FROM 'yourTextFile' 
WITH DELIMITER E'\x19'  /* Use a delimiter that actually NEVER occurs */ ;
```

Delete the last row from the temp table:

```
DELETE FROM
    temp_table 
WHERE 
    serial_id = (SELECT max(serial_id) FROM temp_table) ;
```

Once your data is in your temp table, you can move it to the "definitive" one by using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO
    final_table
    (date_field, something_more)
SELECT
    split_part(all_text, E'\t', 1)::date,
    split_part(all_text, E'\t', 2)::text 
FROM
    temp_table ;
```

If you might have some rows with illegal values, you can discard them by making sure your data follows the right patterns:

```
INSERT INTO
    final_table
    (date_field, something_more)
SELECT
    split_part(all_text, E'\t', 1)::date AS date_field,
    split_part(all_text, E'\t', 2)::text AS something_more 
FROM
    temp_table
WHERE
    split_part(all_text, E'\t', 1) ~ '^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$' ;
```

NOTE: The regexp used ensures that your data looks like '2017-01-04', but it doesn't check for illegal combinations: '2017-02-30' would be considered good by the regexp and still fail when casting to `::date`. If necessary, more sophisticated patterns (or functions) can be used. Check [Type conversion with default fallback value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8833/type-conversion-with-default-fallback-value) for an example.